# How to generate Azure Swagger UI for Function APP

Tags: node.js, azure, api, swagger, swagger-ui

I am new in Azure. I want to generate the Swagger JSON/YAML file for Functoin APP.

When I am trying to generate it from "API defination" it's giving me below alert message.
**"Unable to download Swagger 2.0 metadata. Please verify that the URL is publicly accessible. You may need to enable CORS for the App Service portal extension located at blob://."**
Please suggest me the way to fix this or any other way to generate the Swagger JSON/YAML file / Swagger UI.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try installing `AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle` nuget package - the implementation of which is well explained [here](https://medium.com/@yuka1984/open-api-swagger-and-swagger-ui-on-azure-functions-v2-c-a4a460b34b55).

Comment: Thanks for reply @HarshitaSingh-MSFT,
I have already read this document but I am using **Node.js** is there any reference for **Node.js**?

Comment: @pratik, you can go through this documentation to implement OpenAPI definition for javascript or any other supported language - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-api-definition.
Also note that this feature is in preview right now.
Here is where you can generate OpenAPI definition for your function app - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition#download-the-openapi-definition

Comment: @HarshitaSingh, when you deploy the function app to the Azure APIM, where does the API meta information come from when you client on 'Download OpenApi definition'? The path, methods, etc. are defined within the code but where can you place the details? Like a general description of the API, or tags, etc.